# Spring - Inject bean from a factory class

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have the following in my class:

```
public class Manager {        
    private Apple apple = AppleFactory.createInstance();
    // .....
}
```

appContext.xml:

```
<bean id="manager" class="Manager"/>
```

AppleFactory is an external library on which I do not have any control over. I use xml configuration(appContext.xml) for wiring the beans. How can I inject the field apple from appContext.xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<bean id="apple" class="AppleFactory" factory-method="createInstance" />
<bean id="manager" class="Manager"/>
<context:annotation-config />
```

Your manager

```
public class Manager {

    @Autowired
    private Apple apple;

}
```

Should do the trick.

See [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-class-static-factory-method) and [Initializing Spring bean from static method from another Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885203/initializing-spring-bean-from-static-method-from-another-class)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following configuration :

```
<bean id="apple" class="jarpackagename.AppleFactory"
      factory-method="createInstance">
</bean>

<bean id="manager" class="pkgname.Manager">
    <property name="apple" ref="apple">
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Manager bean as follows

```
<bean class="xxx.Manager">
    <property name="apple">
        <bean class="yyy.AppleFactory" factory-method="createInstance" />
    </property>
</bean>
```